# Backbone underscore lambda or conditional branching?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

very new to [Backbone](https://backbonejs.org/) and JavaScript and I have the following statement I created to branch on logic:

```js
if (config.version !== 'undefined') {
    Mgr.useViews().setViews({});  /** hide the div1 view layout **/
} else {
    Mgr.useViews().setViews({     /** show the div1 view layout **/
        '#div1': new Div1View({
            model: myDiv1Model
        })
    });                
}
```

What is a more effective way to use lambda or another construct within the `SetViews()` method instead of wrapping it entirely with an `if` statement?

Something like:

```js
Mgr.useViews().setViews({
    /** if (config.version === 'undefined') {**/ <= not sure what this could be?                  
        '#div1': new Div1View({
            model: myDiv1Model
        })
/** } **/
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a conditional expression

```
var views = (config.version !== 'undefined') ? {} : {
            '#div1': new Div1View({
                model: myDiv1Model
            })
        };
 Mgr.useViews().setViews(views);
```

Related: are you really sure you want to check for the *string* `'undefined'`?

Comment: thx for the help.  as far as checking for 'undefined' what is your recommendation?  i'm checking the existence of an http header in .jsp/jstl world and if it doesn't come in i set the variable to 'undefined' string literal explicitly.  what would you recommend here for that use case and storing that variable and then adding a conditional check on?